# Python: How do I get a variable to print as a result of another variable being selected by randChoice?

Tags: python, list

I am an APCSP student in high school and one of our open-ended assignments is to create a program that has an educational function. Here is the specific Python function I'll be calling in the main program:

```
def worldStudyQuestions():
    worldStudying = True
    while worldStudying:
        print ("Thanks for studying world history!")
        print ("This study guide consists of ten questions about ancient religions. \n")
        w1 = "Which religion focused on the preservation of all natural things?"
        w1Ans = "Jainism required adherents to move slowly so as to not kill souls living in different objects."
        w2 = "Was the Roman state religion monotheistic or polytheistic?"
        w2Ans = "Polytheistic; they based their gods on the Greek gods."
        w3 = "What was the Buddha's original name?"
        w3Ans = "Siddhartha Gautama"
        w4 = "Which Greek cult often fled to the mountains to drink wine?"
        w4Ans = "Cult of Dionysus"
        w5 = "How many tribes of Israel existed?"
        w5Ans = "Twelve"
        w6 = "Did Confucians look up to a god?"
        w6Ans = "No, they were primarily philosophical."
        w7 = "Where did Gabriel first make contact with Muhammad?"
        w7Ans = "In a cave near Mecca."
        w8 = "What attracted the lower classes to Hinduism?"
        w8Ans = "Hinduism disregarded the traditional caste system of imperial India."
        w9 = ""
        w9Ans = ""
        w0 = ""
        w0Ans = ""
        worldQuestionList = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, w9, w0]
        worldAnsList = [w1Ans, w2Ans, w3Ans, w4Ans, w5Ans, w6Ans, w7Ans, w8Ans, w9Ans, w0Ans]
        print ("Question 1:", random.choice(worldQuestionList))
        worldStudying = False
```

Say random.choice selects w5 from worldQuestionList, I'd like w5Ans to be displayed when the user enters an empty string and then have w5 be removed from the randomization process on the next iteration. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You need a better way of linking a question to its answer.  A dictionary seems like a good fit here, or even just a list of question/answer tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Bamer's answer is surely elegant, you may get a better understanding with this approach; it maps the questions and answers, using a dictionary of data, and a mapping of questions to answers:

```
import random

dataset = {
        'w1': "Which religion focused on the preservation of all natural things?",
        'w1Ans': "Jainism required adherents to move slowly so as to not kill souls living in different objects.",
        'w2': "Was the Roman state religion monotheistic or polytheistic?",
        'w2Ans': "Polytheistic; they based their gods on the Greek gods.",
        'w3': "What was the Buddha's original name?",
        'w3Ans': "Siddhartha Gautama",
        'w4': "Which Greek cult often fled to the mountains to drink wine?",
        'w4Ans': "Cult of Dionysus",
        'w5': "How many tribes of Israel existed?",
        'w5Ans': "Twelve",
        'w6': "Did Confucians look up to a god?",
        'w6Ans': "No, they were primarily philosophical.",
        'w7': "Where did Gabriel first make contact with Muhammad?",
        'w7Ans': "In a cave near Mecca.",
        'w8': "What attracted the lower classes to Hinduism?",
        'w8Ans': "Hinduism disregarded the traditional caste system of imperial India.",
        'w9': "",
        'w9Ans': "",
        'w0': "",
        'w0Ans': ""
        }

worldQuestionList = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6', 'w7', 'w8', 'w9', 'w0']
worldAnsList = ['w1Ans', 'w2Ans', 'w3Ans', 'w4Ans', 'w5Ans', 'w6Ans', 'w7Ans', 'w8Ans', 'w9Ans', 'w0Ans']

question_to_answer = {q: a for q, a in zip(worldQuestionList, worldAnsList)}
# this is a dictionary comprehension.
# it creates a mapping (dictionary) between questions keys and answers keys:
# {w1: 'w1Ans', 'w2': w2Ans', ...}
# this "lookup table" is used to access the questions and their corresponding answers

def worldStudyQuestions():
    worldStudying = True

    while worldStudying:
        print ("Thanks for studying world history!")
        print ("This study guide consists of ten questions about ancient religions. \n")
        question = random.choice(worldQuestionList)
        print("Question 1:", dataset[question])
        print("Answer 1:", dataset[question_to_answer[question]])
        worldStudying = False

worldStudyQuestions()
```

Comment: Could you clarify the line that reads: question_to_answer = {q: a for q, a in zip(worldQuestionList, worldAnsList)} I'm not too sure how this is functioning.

Comment: Sure, I added an explanation.

Comment: How would I eliminate an entry from worldQuestionList so it isn't selected anymore?

Comment: The way the data is currently structured: with great pain... it is feasible, but then your next question is "how to add a new pair of question/answer?"... and then it becomes completely un-manageable.
You need to restructure your code so that question and answer pairs are stored together in a class that will support adding and removing, and the other operations you need.
I am afraid my answer to your question is showing its limitations; but then, your original question also had a limited scope.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question, based on my answer, about how to restructure the data to support the operations you need?

Answer (score 1):

Simple just pop the question and answer from the list after user answered it. Just Like

```
ch=random.randint(0,len(worldQuestionList))
print ("Question 1:",worldQuestionList[ch])
#Use same for answer like worldAnsList[ch]
# Finally Remove both like below
worldQuestionList.pop(ch)
worldAnsList.pop(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two different lists, use a list of dictionaries.

```
worldQAList = [ {question: w1, answer: w1Ans}, {question: w2, answer: w2Ans}, ...]
selected = random.choice(worldQAList)
print ("Question 1:", selected['question'])
print("Answer is", selected['answer'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for something like this:

```
def worldStudyQuestions():
    worldStudying = True
    qa = {'question1': 'answer1', 'question2': 'answer2', 'question3': 'answer3'}
    questions = list(qa.keys())
    while len(questions) > 0:
        print ("Thanks for studying world history!")
        choice = random.choice(questions)
        print("Question: " + choice)
        print("Answer: " + qa[choice])
        questions.remove(choice)
```

What it does is basically map questions to answers in a dictionary. Then, we take a list of all questions (keys of the dictionary), and randomly pick one. Once the choice is made, we can take a corresponding answer. We then remove the choice from the `questions` and continue iteration.